# Why does the lebesgue differentiation theorem not work for arbitrary measures?

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I was looking through the proof for the Lebesgue differentiation theorem which is defined only for a lebesgue measure. If it was any other measure then it may not hold.

However, going through the proof I didn't find any places that I felt wouldn't also be true for an arbitrary measure.

Firstly, you prove the Lebesgue differentiation theorem is true for continuous functions. This seems to be true even for non lebesgue measures because we are just using the uniform continuity property.

Secondly, we used the fact that continuous functions are dense in L2 to pick a continuous function close to our arbitrary L2 function for which we want to show the general case of the theorem. Again, i don't see why the Lebesgue measure is any special.

Why would this not work for an arbitrary measure?

Answer (score 7):

Lebesgue's differentiation theorem **does** hold for a much larger class of measures; it is not restricted to Lebesgue measure. The following statement is compiled from *Measure Theory Vol. 1* by Bogachev (Theorem 5.8.8).

> Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ which is finite on all balls. If $f \in L^1(\mu)$, then $$f(x) = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{\mu(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} f(y) \, \mu(dy)$$ for $\mu$-almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

More generally it is possible to consider measures on "nice" metric spaces, see e.g. Chapter 2 in *Geometric Measure Theory* by Federer for details.

Comment: Is the proof of this theorem similar to the proof of the theorem with Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Qwertford Well, I've no idea which proof you know. But I guess it's not very close to the proof which you know because Bogachev proves it in a more abstract framework

Comment: I mean why can't they be the same proof? Why would the proof for lebesgue measure not work for arbitrary measures?

Comment: @Qwertford Since the result **does** hold for (quite) general measures, it may be possible to generalize certain proofs from Lebesgue measure to general measures... you just have to be really careful. For instance, in "your" proof, you are using that the continuous functions are dense in $L^2$. Mind that this is not true for general measure spaces... there are measures $\mu$ for which there doesn't even exist a (non-trivial) continuous functionwhich is integrable.